# Display row with condition in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Assume I have one data set with following fields:
Name, Amount, Time, etc

How can I display only those records with Amount > 100, for example?

Since I need this data set for other report, I can't filter these records when I prepare data set.

I searched around, but couldn't find any answer. I will really appreciate if anyone can help.

By the way, I used Pentaho Report Designer 3.9.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

You have to find your Details Band - not Details Body -, within your Report Structure, and set up the Style Attribute *visible* the expression:

```
=if([Amount]>100;true();false())
```

Besides, if you want your summaries to consider only the shown data, you can also add an Open Formula function field, that would say:

```
=if([Amount]>100;[Amount];0)
```

And you'd summarize it at the end of the report.

Here's the [link with the full example](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx8Uvvq7ud_UaFdyMmtxSkwtSFE/edit?usp=sharing) built to your situation.